# Laravel missing required parameter for [Route: show] [URI: {lang}/listings/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a CRUD app with login/register and localization functionalities in laravel 9. I have a list of posts in my index page which each have a link to a page that displays the single post.
everything worked well before i added the localization functionality but now when I try to get a single post I get this error:

> Missing required parameter for [Route: show] [URI: {lang}/listings/{id}] [Missing parameter: id].

Here's my code:

The link components in view that goes to the show single post page:

```html
<h3 class="text-2xl">
    <a href="{{ route('show', ['id' => $listing->id, 'lang' => App::getLocale()]) }}">
        {{ $listing->title }}
    </a>
</h3>
```

The route for the show page in my `routes/web.php`:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}'], function () {
    Route::get('/listings/{id}', [listingController::class, 'show'])
        ->name('show');
});
```

The show function in controllers/listingController.php:

```php
public function show($lang, $id)
{
    $listing = Listing::find($id);

    return $listing ? view('listings.show', ['listing' => $listing]) : abort('404');
}
```

I'm passing both the lang and id parameters but I still get the missing parameters error.

The `$listing` variable in my view page is passed through `Listing` model and `listingController`. It contains all the listing posts and is not `null`, so I know that's not causing the issue.

---

Edit: these are all the routes after running PHP artisan route:list command

```
ANY       / ..................................................................................... Illuminate\Routing › RedirectController
POST      _ignition/execute-solution ...................... ignition.executeSolution › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › ExecuteSolutionController
GET|HEAD  _ignition/health-check .................................. ignition.healthCheck › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › HealthCheckController  
POST      _ignition/update-config ............................... ignition.updateConfig › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › UpdateConfigController  
GET|HEAD  api/user ......................................................................................................................  
GET|HEAD  sanctum/csrf-cookie ......................................... sanctum.csrf-cookie › Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show  
GET|HEAD  {lang} ........................................................................................ index › listingController@index  
POST      {lang}/listings ....................................................................... listingsStore › listingController@store  
GET|HEAD  {lang}/listings/create .............................................................. listingsCreate › listingController@create
GET|HEAD  {lang}/listings/manage ...................................................................... manage › listingController@manage  
GET|HEAD  {lang}/listings/{id} ............................................................................ show › listingController@show  
PUT       {lang}/listings/{listing} ........................................................... listingsUpdate › listingController@update
DELETE    {lang}/listings/{listing} ......................................................... listingsDestroy › listingController@destroy  
GET|HEAD  {lang}/listings/{listing}/edit .......................................................... listingsEdit › listingController@edit  
POST      {lang}/logout .................................................................................. logout › userController@logout  
GET|HEAD  {lang}/register .............................................................................. register › userController@create
POST      {lang}/users ..................................................................................... users › userController@store  
POST      {lang}/users/authenticate .......................................................... authenticate › userController@authenticate  
GET|HEAD  {lang}/users/login ............................................................................... login › userController@login
```

Edit 2:
My listing.show view file:

```
<x-layout>
@include('partials/_search')

<a href="/" class="inline-block text-black ml-4 mb-4"
><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i> Back
</a>
<div class="mx-4">
<x-card class="p-10">
    <div
        class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-center"
    >
        <img
            class="w-48 mr-6 mb-6"
            src="{{$listing->logo ? asset('storage/' . $listing->logo) : asset('images/no-image.png')}}"
            alt=""
        />

        <h3 class="text-2xl mb-2">
            {{$listing->title}}
        </h3>
        <div class="text-xl font-bold mb-4">
            {{$listing->company}}
        </div>
    
        <x-listing-tags :tags="$listing->tags"/>

        <div class="text-lg my-4">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
            {{$listing->location}}
        </div>
        <div class="border border-gray-200 w-full mb-6"></div>
        <div>
            <h3 class="text-3xl font-bold mb-4">
                Job Description
            </h3>
            <div class="text-lg space-y-6">
                {{$listing->description}}
                <a
                    href="mailto:{{$listing->email}}"
                    class="block bg-laravel text-white mt-6 py-2 rounded-xl hover:opacity-80"
                    ><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
                    Contact Employer</a
                >

                <a
                    href="{{$listing->website}}"
                    target="_blank"
                    class="block bg-black text-white py-2 rounded-xl hover:opacity-80"
                    ><i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i> Visit
                    Website</a
                >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-card>
</div>
```

Comment: In the route named "show" you do not accept a variable `{lang}` , yet you are trying to redirect to it in your blade file `['id' => $listing->id, 'lang' => App::getLocale()]` it is only accepting an `{id}`

Comment: I forgot to add. my routes are wrapped in a route group with the prefix {lang}.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense, can you run this command 
`php artisan view:clear` and 
`php artisan route:clear` and tell me if this issue is still happening?

Comment: yes, the issue still stands.

Comment: In your post page, hover your mouse over the link, does it look like `yoursite.com/eng/listings/992`

Comment: yes this is the url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/listings/1

Comment: can you do `php artisan route:list` and paste the content in your question, it looks like you have another route that is named "show" that is conflicting

Comment: Did you try passing `$listing` like this: `view('listings.show')->with(['listing' => $listing])` and what happens if you use: `findOrFail` instead of just `find`?

Comment: done, didn't work. thanks anyways.

Comment: What does the `lists.show` view look like, because it looks like that is where the failing route is defined. Do you use the same link component in the single post page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a link in a component within a component within my layout component (3 times nested) that passed only one param, I fixed it by adding another param. It's always a better idea to do localization before defining your routes so that you notice an error immediately instead of having to spend hours going through all your view files.